# Android camera accessing "outside current field of view" on zoom in

Tags: android, android-camera, zooming

Here is an interesting problem I am trying to solve.

In my app I have extended SurfaceView to create a custom cameraview. And now I want to implement ZOOM and PAN functionality in it. Following are the steps;

With my Android device properly mounted(still in a position)
1) I will zoom in on the camera view

2)Now I can pan with my finger on the camera view. As the device is NOT MOVING and I am trying to pan on cameraview(which is "zoomed in"), I want camera view to start showing preview of areas which were outside the scope of "current view" after zoom in(but were visible before I zoomed in).

Do you think this functionality is possible in Andorid today?

I am trying to explain the problem in this picture

Comment: there is no Picture? i don't really understand what's your Goal ...